# Can I cancel iTunes Match and subscribe again without reuploading my music?

Tags: itunes-match

If I decide to cancel iTunes Match for a bit and then resubscribe do I go through the whole 'match' process for my music again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually wrote an article on this.  The relevant part:

> When you end your iTunes Match sub, you can only access songs you’ve
>   downloaded, they will not be available to download after the sub ends.
>   You can continue to play the songs that exist on your device.
>
> Your iTunes Match library will only be stored online for 30 days after
>   you cancel.

http://demianturner.com/2015/11/itunes-match-vs-apple-music/